# Objective-C: use NSThread with a function or block, without need for an additional object

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

I have an Objective-C app where I need to run a function in a separate thread. This function will run continuously with a run loop and will need to be canceled at a later date, so I think the right thing to use is `NSThread`. I don't think this is an appropriate time to use Grand Central Dispatch. (Do correct me if I'm wrong.)

`NSThread` requires me to allocate and maintain a separate object with a method that will be executed in the new thread, e.g. `[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:someObject selector:@selector(runThread) object:nil]`

Granted this may seem like a trifling complaint, but is there any way for me to start a thread like this without needing this separate object? I'd like to just use a C-style function or a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is organized a bit oddly, but `NSThread` has [`-initWithBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsthread/2088561-initwithblock?language=objc) and [`+detachNewThreadWithBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsthread/2088563-detachnewthreadwithblock?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Why on earth would `-initWithBlock:` not be listed with the rest of the initializers? Why is `+detachNewThreadWithBlock:` not listed under "Starting a Thread"? That is some bad organization right there!